# Get values from an xml (4 levels)

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7, xml-serialization

Help for values ​​in a xml at various levels.

This is the xml:

```
<widgets>
    <id>95</id>

    <widget type="1" name="accventas" caption="Ofertas ventas" flags="4">
        <service name="pm_venofer_total00001" caption="Pendientes de aceptar" desc="" type="3" detail="1">
            <xvalue>20</xvalue>
            <xcolor>1</xcolor>
        </service>
    </widget>

    <widget type="3" name="today_state" caption="Estado de ventas" flags="4">
        <service name="pd_today_orders00001" caption="Pedidos" desc="Nº pedidos del día" type="3" detail="1">
            <xvalue>0</xvalue>
            <xcolor>2</xcolor>
            <xalert>No se está vendiendo nada</xalert>
        </service>

        <service name="pd_today_sales00001" caption="Importe" desc="Importe ventas del día" type="3" detail="1">
            <xvalue>0,00</xvalue>
            <xcolor>2</xcolor>
            <xalert>No estamos recaudando nada</xalert>
        </service>
    </widget>
</widgets>
```

Loaded the xml and is ready to be tried, but I can not get all the fields you need

I need:

- id,
- caption attribute of the widget,
- the services of each widget,
- the caption attribute of service,
- xValue,
- xcolor and xalert,
- each service

I get to get all the widgets, like this: (I think two kinds: `Employees` and `Employee`)

```
[XmlRoot("widgets")]
public class Employees
{
    [XmlElement("widget")]
    public ObservableCollection <Employee> Coleccion { get; set; }
}


 public class Employee
 {
    [XmlAttribute("caption")]
    public string nombreWidget { get; set; }
 }
```

But not like getting inside each widget their respective services (service attribute), and within these xValue, xcolor and xalert

Comment: Have you considered using Linq to XML or XPATH? Or do you have to use `XmlSerializer`?

Comment: I'm working with LINQ to XML, because unfortunately XPath not currently supported, and with linq not getting to all tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**LinqToXml solution:**

```
var xml = XDocument.Parse(Resource1.XMLFile1).Root;
var parsed = new {
                     Id = xml.Element("id").Value,
                     Widgets = xml.Elements("widget")
                                  .Select(w => new
                                  {
                                      Caption = w.Attribute("caption").Value,
                                      Services = w.Elements("service").Select(s => new
                                      {
                                          Caption = s.Attribute("caption").Value,
                                          XColor = s.Element("xcolor").Value,
                                          XValue = s.Element("xvalue").Value,
                                          XAlert = s.Element("xalert") != null ? s.Element("xalert").Value : null
                                      }).ToList()
                                  }).ToList()
                 };
```

It will creates anonymous objects representing your inpout XML. You can easily replace that anonymous objects from my code with your real domain objects (`Employees` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You should use XPATH

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

Then do something like this:

```
XPathNavigator nav;
XPathDocument docNav;
XPathNodeIterator NodeIter;
String strExpression;

// Open the XML.
docNav = new XPathDocument(@"c:\books.xml");

// Create a navigator to query with XPath.
nav = docNav.CreateNavigator();

// Find the average cost of a book.
// This expression uses standard XPath syntax.
strExpression = "sum(/bookstore/book/price) div count(/bookstore/book/price)";
```

For more information about everything that can be achieved using XPATH consider:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/XPath

Comment: I am working on a Window Phone app were I need to use xpath with linq. Unfortunately xpath is not currently supported.

Answer (score 0):

95

```
<widget type="1" name="accventas" caption="Ofertas ventas" flags="4">
    <service name="pm_venofer_total00001" caption="Pendientes de aceptar" desc="" type="3" detail="1">
        <xvalue>20</xvalue>
        <xcolor>1</xcolor>
    </service>
</widget>

<widget type="3" name="today_state" caption="Estado de ventas" flags="4">
    <service name="pd_today_orders00001" caption="Pedidos" desc="Nº pedidos del día" type="3" detail="1">
        <xvalue>0</xvalue>
        <xcolor>2</xcolor>
        <xalert>No se está vendiendo nada</xalert>
    </service>

    <service name="pd_today_sales00001" caption="Importe" desc="Importe ventas del día" type="3" detail="1">
        <xvalue>0,00</xvalue>
        <xcolor>2</xcolor>
        <xalert>No estamos recaudando nada</xalert>
    </service>
</widget>
```

Comment: You need to explain your code, why is this an answer to the quetion?

Comment: Hi Matt, welcome to Stack Overflow . While this might answer the authors' question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.